# While loop in Python not working out

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, while-loop

So I just started out with python recently and I tried using a while loop in the code but when I click run, the program just runs forever without printing anything. I did some research on while loops but I didn't find anything that would help me. Here is the code in its entirety:

```
import random  
HeroHP = random.randint(120 , 120)  
WitchHP = random.randint(100 , 100)  
Alive = 1  
Dead = 0  
if WitchHP > 0:  
    WitchStatus = Alive  
if WitchHP < 1:  
    WitchStatus = Dead  
if HeroHP > 0:  
    HeroStatus = Alive  
if HeroHP < 1:  
    HeroStatus = Dead  
HeroCritChance = random.randint(0 , 2)  
if HeroCritChance == 2:  
    HeroATK = 25  
if HeroCritChance == 0 or FriskCritChance == 1:  
    HeroATK = 10  
WitchHitChance = random.randint(0 , 1)  
if WitchHitChance == 0:  
    WitchATK = 30  
if WitchHitChance == 1:  
    WitchATK = 0  
while WitchStatus == Alive and HeroStatus == Alive:  
    WitchHP = WitchHP - HeroATK  
    HeroHP = HeroHP - WitchATK  
if WitchStatus == Alive and HeroStatus == Dead:  
    print ("the Hero has been defeated...")  
if WitchStatus == Dead and HeroStatus == Alive:  
    print ("the Hero has triumphed!")  
if WitchStatus == Dead and HeroStatus == Dead:  
    print ("Peace has returned... But at a price...")
```

(Sorry if I'm making a very silly mistake, as I mentioned earlier, I'm really new to coding in general.)

Comment: Well, you never change `WitchStatus` or `HeroStatus` in your while loop, so yeah, it'll never leave that loop.

Comment: @MorganThrapp To elaborate, you would need to put your if HeroHP < 1 bit inside the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python the assignment operation does not work that way.

It looks like when you write:

```
if WitchHP > 0:  
    WitchStatus = Alive
```

You think that using `WitchStatus` in a future condition it will actually check the value of `WitchHP`. But that's not the case, it does the secuence: first it evaluates the condition, then if that is true it assigns to `WitchStatus`. If then, the value of `WitchHP` changes, the `WitchStatus` will not change, unless you run this statement again.

What you want is a function:

```
def WitchStatus():
    if  WitchHP > 0:
        return Alive
    else:
        return Dead

while WitchStatus() == Alive:
    WitchHP = WitchHP - HeroATK
```

Then, every time you use the function with `WitchStatus()` the program will check the condition again.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
while WitchStatus == Alive and HeroStatus == Alive:  
    WitchHP = WitchHP - HeroATK  
    HeroHP = HeroHP - WitchATK
```

To an if statement:

```
if WitchStatus == Alive.....
```

In the original, once WitchStatus == Alive, it will remain that way and the loop will keep running because there is nothing that changes it. It's like forgetting to add the i = i + 1 line in a numerically counted loop.